# running nunit GUI in single-threaded mode

Tags: c++, com, nunit

is there a possibility to run n-unit GUI the same way as n-unit console with /nothread parameter? We're doing some nasty things in our single-threaded app written in C++ and testing it in n-unit over COM. The thing is everything is OK, when the tests are ran in console runner. But the gui runner fails to run some of the tests with ESP run-time checks violation. I've tried the RequireSTA attribute on the whole assembly, test-fixture or test-case. But nothing helps :(

Comment: I expect this isn't possible, since doing so would mean running the tests on the UI thread which would lock up the UI while the tests are running.

Comment: Well basically I would care for that ;) The GUI may update between the tests ...

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar problems. I ran the test suites with nunit-x86.exe instead, to avoid 64 bit issues.

Comment: yes we use the x86 version, but the problem is the traversing between multiple threads :/

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems, because if I'm not mistaken, each test fixture is run in a single thread, meaning that [SetUp], [TearDown] and each [Test] are run in the same thread. What kind of errors are you getting? Could you post some stack traces?